# converting byte array data to image formate in ios

Tags: objective-c-blocks

i am trying to convert byte array to image formate but iam facing an error like 
" **: ImageIO: JPEG Bogus DQT index 15**", can any body help me out of it,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Without other informations i can say that: You can get the bytes in NSData and use the NSData to get the image in an UIImage object. Use initWithData method.

Comment: thanks for comment.....                                   img_view.image=[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithBytes:chararray length : sizeof(theResultLength)]];                                            here i am trying to get data from char array and converting that data to image is it correct? is there any other way to convert byte array to image?

Comment: Try with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660482/byte-array-to-uiimage-objective-c/6660543#6660543

Comment: Are you sure that your data isn't corrupted?

Comment: It's strange, because this error is given when the source is corrupted, can you try with jpegsnoop utility or something like it to test it's authenticity?@user2361155